# How can I find all the possible cron settings?

Tags: cron, environment-variables

I recently discovered that `cron` (at least on Ubuntu 14+) supports a setting called `CONTENT_TYPE` where I can specify the content type for emails like:

```
CONTENT_TYPE="text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

On another non-Ubuntu server I use the version does not support this.  I looked at every man page I could find to no avail.  Is there a way to find out all of the supported settings for a given version of `cron`?

Answer (score 4):

It is mentioned in the `man` page, you just need to look at the right one.

From [`man 5 crontab`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/crontab.5.html):

```
By  default,  cron will send mail using the mail "Content-Type:" header
of "text/plain" with the "charset=" parameter  set  to  the  charmap  /
codeset  of the locale in which crond(8) is started up - ie. either the
default system locale, if no LC_* environment variables are set, or the
locale  specified  by  the LC_* environment variables ( see locale(7)).
You can use different character encodings for mailed cron job output by
setting  the  CONTENT_TYPE  and  CONTENT_TRANSFER_ENCODING variables in
crontabs, to the correct values of the mail headers of those names.
```

Now you might ask how do i know which one to look at. Well, from `man man` :

> The table below shows the section numbers of the manual followed by
>   the types of pages they contain.
>
> ```
>    1   Executable programs or shell commands
>    2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
>    3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
>    4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
>    5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
>    6   Games
>    7   Miscellaneous (including macro packages and conventions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
>    8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
>    9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
> ```

Comment: I cannot find the quoted text in only the 12.04 manpage, not in 14.04 or later.

Comment: @muru I have quoted it from my 14.04..could you recheck ?

Comment: See for yourself: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/crontab.5.html

Comment: @muru That man page starts with ` A  crontab  file  contains instructions to the bcron-sched(8) daemon...` ..i think thats for `bcron`

Comment: Hmm. Looks like I have been bitten by https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-manpage-repository/+bug/606456.

Comment: I'll leave the link, in case anyone wants to read the whole thing online and couldn't find the right page.

Comment: This does not answer my question.  I want to know ALL the possible settings.  Not only does my man page differ and not mention the setting in question, it does not mention any settings at all ... not even the `MAILTO` setting.